# How to destruct `data-*` (hyphen cased) attributes from props?

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx

Im trying to convert one of my components to a functional stateless component (FSC).

But FSC will not be optimized if using `...rest`, therefore i need to destruct the components props.

I call Link as

```
<Link to={link} data-navbar-click="close-menu">{name}</Link>
```

then in Link i want to destruct the **hyphen cased> data-navbar-click** prop:

```
function Link({ to, className, onClick, target, rel, key, data-navbar-click}) {
```

However that doesnt compile. So i tried:

```
function Link({ to, className, onClick, target, rel, key, ['data-navbar-click']}) {
```

But that doesnt work as well.

Comment: What do you mean it won't be optimized, have a link?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Simplest solution: use alias.

```
const Link = ({
  to,
  className,
  onClick,
  target,
  rel,
  key,
  'data-navbar-click': dataNavbarClick,
}) => {
  const test = dataNavbarClick;
};
```

dataNavbarClick should have the value "close-menu"

Answer (score 2):

You can write a utility function that transforms `camelCase` key names to kebab/hyphen-case properties, picked them out out of the props object and, by using JSX spread, render them in the component.

Example below:

```
import kebabCase from 'lodash/kebabCase';

const props = {
  dataNavAttr: 'close-menu',
  itemCount: 100
}

const pickAndTransformDataProps = (props, findByKey) => {
  const pickedProps = {};
  Object.keys(props).map(key => {
    if (key.includes(findByKey)){
      pickedProps[kebabCase(key)] = props[key];
    }
  });
  return pickedProps;
}

const pickedDataProps = pickAndTransformDataProps(props, 'data');
console.log({ pickedDataProps }); 
// Using JSX spread: <Component onClick={props.onClick} { ...pickedDataProps } />
```

Comment: I would have liked it without using an external lib. I noticed i could just do: function `Link(props) {const dataNavbarClick = props['data-navbar-click'];` then do my regular `const { to, className, onClick, target, rel, key} = props}`.. Strange though that i couldnt destruct it

Comment: Well, how about passing in an extra object to props which will contain data attrbute props only? Like `const dataAttrProps = { 'data-link: 'smth', 'etc': 'etc' };` and then simply spread that `dataAttrProps ` in JSX like `{ ...props.dataAttrProps }`. This seems like the cleanest approach to me.